# Prove/Disprove: if REFF of $A,B \in M_{nxn}(\mathbb R)$ is $A_R , B_R$, then REFF of $A+B$ is $(A_R + B_R)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove/Disprove:  if REFF of $A,B \in M_{nxn}(\mathbb R)$ is $A_R , B_R$, then REFF of $A+B$ is $(A_R + B_R)$

How do i approach this one? thanks in advance.

(REFF is Row Echelon Form.)

Comment: REFF?${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @martini Reduced echelon form... something.

Comment: It can't be the *reduced* row echolon form, since $\operatorname{rref}(A+A) = \operatorname{rref}(A)$. I guess it is some sort of canonical row echolon form, where you are not allowed to multiply rows by non-zero scalars, so the leading coefficients in the rows are uniquely determined and differ for $2A$ and $A$.